# A question about nicotinamide adenine dinucleotide

Tags: organic-chemistry, ions, ionic-compounds, chemical-biology, nitro-compounds

In the structure of NAD+, why does the nitrogen of pyridine bind covalently to the the first carbon of glucose while the anion stabilizing the nicotine amide ion is the phosphate group? In other words, why didn't NAD+ exist as an ionic salt between nicotine amide ion and phosphate ion in the  nucleotide?